# Set content value of itemprop with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Html:

```
<meta itemprop="price" content="34,95&nbsp;€ " />
```

I need to update price dynamically. To get it I use:

```
$('meta[itemprop="price"]').attr('content');
```

Which method can be used to replace price?

Comment: isn't it better to go to the documentation. just suggesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply give the `attr` function a second argument which is the value.

```
$('meta[itemprop="price"]').attr('content', 'newContent');
//newContent doesn't have to be in quotes, it can be a variable too
```

Read more about `attr` [here](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Answer (score 3):

```
$('meta[itemprop="price"]').attr('content', newValue);
```

`.attr( attributeName )` is a getter

`.attr( attributeName, value )` is a setter

You can read more here: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 2):

To replace an attribute's value, give two arguments to `.attr()`:

```
$('meta[itemprop="price"]').attr('content', newPrice);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('meta[itemprop="price"]').attr('content',"<<new price>>");
```

Let me know if this works.